# How to display the domain name in the subject line using an exiting PHP form

Tags: php, email

Current form works great, and is implemented across numerous domains, however the subject line is the same. I would like to deploy a form across multiple domains w/out having to manually enter “SPECIFIC_DOMAIN.com” to each form subject line. Is there a way to have the Subject line denote which URL the contact form is coming from dynamically? Current subject line is static: “Contact Mail”. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    require('constant.php');
    
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_phone     = filter_var($_POST["phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $content   = filter_var($_POST["content"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    if(empty($user_name)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Name</b>";       
    }
    if(empty($user_email)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Email</b>";
    }
    if(empty($user_phone)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Phone Number</b>";
    }   
    if(empty($content)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Comments</b>";
    }
    
    if(!empty($empty)) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => implode(", ",$empty) . ' Required!'));
        die($output);
    }
    
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>'.$user_email.'</b> is an invalid Email, please correct it.'));
        die($output);
    }
    
    //reCAPTCHA validation
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        
        require('component/recaptcha/src/autoload.php');        
        
        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY);

        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

          if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
                $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>Captcha</b> Validation Required!'));
                die($output);               
          } 
    }
    
    $toEmail = "badassdomain@aol.com";
    $mailHeaders = "From: " . $user_name . "<" . $user_email . ">\r\n";
    $mailBody = "User Name: " . $user_name . "\n";
    $mailBody .= "User Email: " . $user_email . "\n";
    $mailBody .= "Phone: " . $user_phone . "\n";
    $mailBody .= "Content: " . $content . "\n";

    if (mail($toEmail, "Contact Mail", $mailBody, $mailHeaders)) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hey there '.$user_name .'! Your message is on the way. Cheers.'));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Unable to send email, please contact'.SENDER_EMAIL));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can use variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` which has a URL of the referring page, so that will be a page where form is hosted. If your script is hosted on different sites, you can also use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable to show domain name of the website where the script is hosted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this simply by changing:

```
if (mail($toEmail, "Contact Mail", $mailBody, $mailHeaders)) {
```

To

```
$sub = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if (mail($toEmail, $sub, $mailBody, $mailHeaders)) {
```

You might want to consider using something like:

```
$sub = 'Mail from ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

instead though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
mail($toEmail, "Contact Mail", $mailBody, $mailHeaders)
```

use:

```
mail($toEmail, "Contact Mail from " . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"], $mailBody, $mailHeaders)
```

See: [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server)

Note that `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` is set by the client, which means it is unreliable, whereas `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` is set by the server.